# Using chapter instead of section number with amsthm

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm

I'm trying to number my examples, definitions, theorems, etc. in the form `Chapter#.example#`.
However, the `amsthm` package only seems to provide sectional numbering, which I don't like.

Does anyone know how to get the correct format of numbering?

In the `MWE` the numbering should be: Example 1.1. and Definition 1.1.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[section]
\begin{document}
    \chapter{}
        \section{section 1}
        \begin{exmp}
        \end{exmp}
        \section{section 2}
        \begin{defi}
        \end{defi}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I read this might be possible with `thmtools`, but i'd prefer to do it without loading additional packages if possible. Unless it becomes a to complicated solution ofcourse.

Comment: `\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[chapter]\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[chapter]` works for me.

Comment: Why is it in the manual only explained for [section]... sigh.. it doesn't mention chapter at all. Thanks though, I didn't even consider just trying to see what it did. If you post as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Mythio -- `section` as used in the manual is only a suggestion.  i'll add a note to the update list to make it clear that it's possible to use other segmenting counters instead.  (since the heaviest use of the package is for articles, `section` is more relevant there.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton; yeah I suppose its true that it is used mostly for articles and formats without chapters. I think updating the documentation is a good idea though, thanks for putting it on the list! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the manual doesn't explicitly say so, the following works:

```
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[chapter]
```